# What's eating my plants?

Tags: pest-control, herbs, basil, beans

New gardener here. I saw little holes in my basil, bean, and epazote leaves. What's eating them, and how can I get rid of these pests? Obviously spraying something on the leaves is less than ideal for the herbs.

Pictures are linked to below.

Thank you!

Picture links:
[Basil](https://photos.app.goo.gl/TmDcMeXxwHrEBNrf6)
[Epazote](https://photos.app.goo.gl/kQ5jsmBcDpWDnUCv7)
[Beans](https://photos.app.goo.gl/FMBh9efMX4stD3JR8)

Answer (score 1):

The first two plants look like they have slug damage. This is possibly the case with the third, depending on how large the leaf is (right now, it looks like the holes are too small). A good way to confirm is to either visit the garden at night (especially if it's humid/wet) or to put a beer trap under the plants at ground level. You'll either see the slugs on the leaves or in the beer. You're right to do nothing to the leaves. You could purchase slug pellets (read the label if you have dogs; some pellets, at least, are poisonous) or use beer traps to try to reduce feeding pressure.